# Rough estimates of transaction propagation latency?

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, network, txpool, transaction-propagation

Does anyone know any rough numbers for transaction propagation currently for the Ethereum network? I.e. how long does a submitted transaction take to reach 50%/95%/etc of nodes? Thanks!

Comment: I should note that, from personal experience, my txns appear on Etherscan usually only seconds after submitting them. However, this might not be representative of the entire network, since it's reasonable to believe that Etherscan has set up several clients with a robust set of peer nodes (since they are in the business of reading and delivering blockchain data).